# ASP Net Core 3, set global variable from database and use in view, controllers

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, configuration, global-variables

First of all excuse me for my bad english ...

I'm looking for a way to use a class in all my project. I explain my need to you. Because I don't know where to go.
I'have a web project asp net core connected to sql server. Inside i have a public pages with different section (ex: payment, create, message, ads, register...), and i have a area admin (back office for me).

I have a class :

```
public class Section
{
   public bool RegistrationEnabled { get; set; }
   public bool PaymentEnabled { get; set; }
   public bool PublicationEnabled { get; set; }
   public bool MessageEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

I want this class to allow me to make certain part of the site accessible or not in my views or in my controllers.
Ex in view :

```
@if (Section.RegistrationEnabled)
{ 
   // Display form register..
}
```

The data is saved in a table in sql server (with entity framework), and I must be able to modify it from my admin area. I would like it to be persistent without having to fetch it each time a page is called by a user.
I have explored different solution:

- appSetting: but I can't edit from my admin interface I think?
- Resource file: But I don't think I can edit it directly?
- Singleton?
- Azure ?

I'm out of ideas and I don't know where to go ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, from your answers I tried to produce something that works, but I don't know if it's very relevant.
This is my setting class :

```
[Table("SETTING")]
public class Setting : BaseObject
{
   [Key]
   [StringLength(50)]
   public string Key { get; set; }
   [StringLength(50)]
   public string Value { get; set; }
   public e_SettingType Type { get; set; }
}
public enum e_SettingType
{
   UNDEFINED,
   BOOL,
   BYTE,
   CHAR,
   DECIMAL,
   DOUBLE,
   FLOAT,
   INT,
   STRING,
}
```

And my service :

```
public class SettingService
    {
        private const string CACHE_KEY = "CurrentSetting";
        private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;
        private readonly IBaseRepository<Setting> _setting;
        public SettingService(IMemoryCache cache, IBaseRepository<Setting> setting)
        {
            _cache = cache;
            _setting = setting;
        }
        public async Task<bool> GetBool(string key)
        {
            var settings = await GetFromCache();
            if (settings != null && settings.Any(x => x.Key.Equals(key)))
                return bool.Parse(settings.First(x => x.Key.Equals(key)).Value);
            else
                return default;
        }
        public async Task<string> GetString(string key)
        {
            var settings = await GetFromCache();
            if (settings != null && settings.Any(x => x.Key.Equals(key)))
                return settings.First(x => x.Key.Equals(key)).Value;
            else
                return default;
        }
        private async Task<List<Setting>> GetFromCache()
        {
            if (!_cache.TryGetValue(CACHE_KEY, out List<Setting> data))
            {
                var models = await _setting.FindAll();
                data = models.ToList();

                var cacheOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
                    .SetAbsoluteExpiration(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));

                _cache.Set(CACHE_KEY, data, cacheOptions);
                return data;
            }
            else
                return data;
        }
    }
```

I've add this in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<SettingService>();
}
```

And for consume my setting in my view, i use this :

```
@inject MyProject.Service.SettingService setting //top of view
```

Get in my view :

```
@setting.GetString("MY_KEY").Result
```

But is this relevant? Or good practice?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a broad/general question, but not a difficult problem to solve.

1. You can create a table in your database, e.g. `AppSettings`, with a `Name` and a `Value` string column. Probably you'd want to do this with your normal EF Core code first approach, creating the models, then doing a migration.
2. a) Then, you'll want to create a component that will automatically read these values from the database and insert them into the app configuration. For example [this seems to be a good implementation candidate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#custom-configuration-provider-1).

But, this begs the question when/how do you want this to be updated, since you mention that you don't want it to be read from the database in each request. Still, if you want to make it dynamically configurable, you will need *some* sort of re-reading. Unless you're comfortable restarting your service each time you modify the configuration.

2. b) Another option, instead of the configuration injector above, is to create a custom service, e.g. `AppSettingsService` (or preferably a less general name), that you can register as a singleton scoped service in the container, and inject into your consuming classes. This service would read the values from the DB, cache them in memory, and expose them in an easy to consume way; plus it could expose a method for refreshing the values from the DB.

If you need help with the implementation details of either of the above, let me know and I can add more details and code samples by editing this answer. Without knowing a bit more of your preferences it would be too demanding to cover everything in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic configuration in asp.net core to accomplish this, I think it is the best way and I recommend you to use this approach. you can find a step by step guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/enable-dynamic-configuration-aspnet-core?tabs=core3x).

***Else*** you can get your set of values from the database and store them in the session when the application is started. [[Source]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

First install nuget package - [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session/)

In Startup.cs file

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        // Add these 6 lines
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
        .
        .
        .
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseSession(); //< --- And add this line
        ..............
    }
```

And in C# you can set and retrive values from Session Storage

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

public class SomeController : Controller
{    
    public ActionResult Index()
    {   
      HttpContext.Session.SetString("RegistrationEnabled", true ); // Set Session  
      var registrationEnabled = HttpContext.Session.GetString("RegistrationEnabled"); // Get Value of Session
    }    
}
```